How to plot different colored multiple logistic regressions + equations, ora by third factor
Sample data:
Discount Hit application
0.45   1       prize
0.37   1       prize
0.18   0       prize
0.30   0       prize
0.22   1       prize
0.21   1       prize
0.65   1       yellow
0.31   1       yellow
0.22   0       yellow
0.16   0       yellow
0.30   1       yellow
0.20   1       lime
0.12   1       lime
0.23   0       lime
0.31   0       lime
0.18   1       lime
0.19   1       lime
0.23   1       food
0.19   1       food
0.10   0       food
0.32   0       food
0.20   1       food
0.56   1       food

I am trying to plot the "Discount" as the x variable and the "Hit" as Y variable. I would like to have 4 different colored logistic regression lines for the different "applications" accompanied by their equations. How can this be done?
The code I have so far is:
data <- read.csv("DiscountData.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

fit <- glm(Hit ~ Discount + factor(application), data = data, family = binomial)

ggplot(data = data, 
       aes(x = Discount, y = Hit, color = as.factor(application))

But right now, no data points are showing up and I don't know how to add the logistic regressions

Do you have any code you're tried?

I'm a beginner so don't have much, just edited posted

require("ggplot2")
ggplot(DATASET, aes(x=discount, y=hit, color=application, group=application)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method="lm")

Just change DATASET for the name of your dataframe.

Thanks! it said error, could not find "geom_points()". Additionally, is there a way to get confidence interval shading adding to the plot?

Its because its spelt geom_point() (without an s) :D
geom_smooth() has the "se" (standard error) bar set by default (see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html for ref)
